# How can I find details of local wireless networks and their traffic and congestion from linux?

Tags: wireless-networking

My favourite wireless connection has become sluggish, and I'd like to troubleshoot it.

Insight is always good, and so I'd like to know as much as possible about what's going on.

Are there any linux tools that can tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ettercap](http://ettercap.sourceforge.net) and [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) (use them together) are two stock tools that you can install and get low level information about your network connection.  Neither one is going to translate what you are seeing into, "now do this to increase your performance..."  You have to know what you are looking for/at.  If you want to know as much as possible about what is going on, start here.